# replacing text with data from each column in row n in CSV, running script, repeating

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a CSV file with multiple columns (fixed) and N rows. I need to replace certain text in my script with data/text from every column in n row, run the script, and then repeat with that data from row n+1.

Every idea that I have had is really inefficient. What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Pete

Comment: can you please be more specific?

Comment: I have a python script that contains XML data that I push through an API. I need to run this script 10,000 or so times, but I need to replace certain text in the script with data from a CSV. I have 6 different columns of data and about 10,000 rows.

Comment: You want your code to write code?  Why the extra layer of indirection?  Can't you just write your code to do what you want?

Comment: I don't want it to write code. I just need to replace certain text and then rerun the 'script' that pushes that info through the API.

Comment: @blahbl83:  Yes, but why not turn that script into a function?  Then feed each data set via function call.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski probably a good idea, I am a novice and just trying to get something to work so I was looking for something I have done in a similar situation in another language.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library has `csv` for handling comma separated files.  If you need unicode support, however, you'll need to find a third-party replacement.  In general, the task you are describing can be accomplished as follows:

```
import csv

data_structure = {'id1': 123, 'id2': 456} # identifiers and values

fsock = open(file_path, 'rU')
# rdr = csv.reader(fsock) # this will read the CSV data, producing lists
dict_rdr = csv.DictReader(fsock) # read data as dictionary, using first row as keys
# if you want to read all the rows...
for entry in dict_rdr:
    # update the data structure with data from the file
    data_structure[entry['id_column']] = entry['value_column']
fsock.close()
```

The file would then look something like this:

```
id_column,value_column
id1,789
id2,666
```

After the script runs, the data structure would be:

```
data_structure = {'id1': 789, 'id2': 666}
```

Comment: In the [examples section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) of the `csv` docs there are recipes for handling unicode.